# SocialEngine compose message for user with predefined text

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I have a button on subject's profile (user that is being viewed), when you click on that button it should a send message to that user with predefined message, for example: "Hey, I think your zodiac is Taurus".

Is something like that possible in SE4? I saw that the URL is composed in this way:
`http://website.com/index.php/messages/compose/to/4`

where `4` at the end is the subject's ID. How can I add a custom message to this? Or even if possible, a custom subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, http://website.com/index.php/messages/compose/multi/{your-subject}/to/4..BUt this conversation will be locked conversation...